# CSS Drop Down Menu doesnt work in IE9

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

i have a dropdown menu that doesnt work in IE9 and I have no idea why.

It works fine in firefox and chrome.

This is the link:

http://www.condadoelectricalservices.com/v2/navTest.html

this is my css:

http://www.condadoelectricalservices.com/v2/styles/mainTwo.css

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're using mootools 1.2.0. Try downloading the latest version from http://mootools.net/download.

Also, you're mixing both jQuery and mootools. Is there any reason you have to use some plugins  for jQuery and some for mootools? A quick search on Google lists up a bunch of jQuery alternatives. See something like http://slodive.com/web-development/best-jquery-dropdown-menus/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  Fairly new to the scene, so just trying things out. there is no reason for me to have some plugins for jQuery and some for mootools. think i have got a bit lost on the way. If i download the new version 1.4.1 of mootools core.js then link to it in my scripts will this solve the problem?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but I don't think 1.2.0 is compatible with IE9.